# How to disable the format characters in MySql searching results?

Tags: mysql, sql

By default, I got results like

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| memory | launchTime | newLaunch |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|     26 |       3360 | true      |
|     24 |         47 | false     |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

How could I set the MySql to remove those `+`, `|`, and `-`?

I prefer searching after logging in, i.e. `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: I just typed `MySQL SPECIFY RESULT FORMAT` into Google. I got back some mighty interesting looking hits.

Comment: how about focusing on the where clause for your search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `--silent` option

```
mysql -u<user> -p<userpwd> --silent <dbname>
```

Comment: Remarkably this works, the results are so unreadable I wonder why the heck you would ever want this.

Comment: @JackWM You are more than welcome. No, I don't believe you can do that after log in.